# Apollo GraphQL: Resolver not called on mutation subfield

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am trying to return a Query type from a mutation, which I could make work in some cases but not the way I want it. The problem is not particularly related to the Query type being used, as I found the same behaviour using other types than `Query`.

You can run and modify this code on https://codesandbox.io/s/1z8kjy8m93

**Server**

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello(msg: String): String
  }

  type Mutation {
    someMutation(someArg: String): MutationResponse
  }

  type MutationResponse {
    query: Query
    status: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (root, args, context) => {
      console.log("hello: args = ", args);
      return `${args.msg}, world !`;
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    someMutation: (root, args, context) => {
      console.log("someMutation: args = ", args);
      return { status: `Mute Mute: ${args.someArg}` };
    }
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

**Mutation**

```
mutation mutateMe($mutationArg: String = "YoloMute !", $helloMsg: String = "Yolhello") {
  someMutation(someArg: $mutationArg) {
    status
    query {
      hello(msg: $helloMsg)
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "data": {
    "someMutation": {
      "status": "Mute Mute: YoloMute !",
      "query": null
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the `hello` resolver is not called and the `query` field is `null`.

The `status` field is duly filled by the `someMutation` resolver, but as the `query` field is not resolved there I would expect GraphQL to call an existing resolver for this field, which exists and should be called for the `Query` type.

I found other ways that technically work but are not satisfying:

- Directly returning the Query type works:
  https://codesandbox.io/s/ovr9zpwr7q
- Duplicating lines in the schema
  works: https://codesandbox.io/s/l4yrqzmq6l

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue isn't really specific to the `Query` type, but rather deals with how you've set up your resolvers.

> The status field is duly filled by the someMutation resolver, but as the query field is not resolved there I would expect GraphQL to call an existing resolver for this field, which exists and should be called for the Query type.

There is no resolver for the entire `Query` type, or any other type. Resolvers exist only for individual fields of a particular type. When a resolver isn't defined for a field, GraphQL will default to looking for a property on the parent object with the same name as the field, and will return the value of that property.

Let's walk through your document. The root-level field is:

`someMutation(someArg: $mutationArg)`

The parent value is the **root value** for all root-level mutations. Unless you're using a custom root value, this will typically be an empty object. If you didn't define a resolver for the `someMutation` field of the `Mutation` type, GraphQL would look for a property called `someMutation` in your root value and return that (i.e. undefined, which would be coerced to null in the response). We **do** have a resolver, though, and it returns:

```
{
  status: `Mute Mute: ${args.someArg}`,
}
```

Now, let's resolve the `status` field. Our parent object is the result returned by the parent field's resolver. In this case, the object above. We have no resolver for `status` on `MutationResponse`, so GraphQL looks for a `status` property on the parent -- it finds one and uses that. `status` has a Scalar type, so whatever value is returned by the resolver will be coerced into the appropriate scalar value.

What about the `query` field? Again, we have no resolver for a `query` field on the `MutationResponse`. However, we also don't have a property called `query` on the parent object. So, all GraphQL can do is return null for that field.

Even though the return type for `query` is an `ObjectType`, because it resolves to `null`, any resolvers for fields on that ObjectType will not be fired. Returning null means the object doesn't exist, so we don't need to bother resolving any fields on it. Imagine if a field returned a User object. If it returned null, there would be no need to resolve the user's name, for example.

So... how do we get around this? There's two ways:

Either add a property for `query` to the object returned by `someMutation`'s resolver, like this:

```
{
  status: `Mute Mute: ${args.someArg}`,
  query: {},
}
```

Or, add a resolver for the field:

```
MutationResponse: {
  query: () => {},
},
```

Either way will ensure that the `query` field will resolve to a non-null value (in this case, just an empty object). Because the value resolved is not `null` and the return type is an `ObjectType` (in this case `Query`), **now** the resolvers for that type's fields will be triggered and `hello` will resolve as expected.

Comment: I got mixed up in my vocabulary, what I meant was not "a resolver for the Query type" but "a resolver for this field of the Query type".

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer ! You just gave me a way deeper understanding of how graphql works than I had before. And I was stuck on this problem for 3 weeks now (also exploring a lot of other approaches like batching or refetchQueries) so I cannot even begin to express how grateful I am that people like you help people like me !